# How to return "omit" from Ansible Jinja filter

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have created a filter that at first could return the Python None object / value. The idea was then to use `default(omit)` with this filter. For example

```yaml
- name: Execute script
  command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ some_list }}"
  notify: "{{ item|my_filter|default(omit) }}"
```

Now I noticed that returning `None` or not using a `return` in my code is translated by Jinja into an empty string. As a consequence Ansible will notify an empty string handler which does not exist and then fail.

Is it possible to omit a variable using `default(omit)` when using a Jinja filter on that variable? How?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only want to trigger the handler when your filter returns something. But ansible, will trigger the handler when the task status is `changed`. As far as I know, this behavior can't be modified and just returning an empty string will not work, as you already experienced.

You have several possibilities:

- You can write a `changed_when` condition that returns `true` in case you want to trigger the handler, and otherwise returns `false`.
- You can define an "empty" handler, that does nothing and trigger that by default (as in when you do not want to trigger the actual handler: `default("empty handler")`).

Everything between `{{` and `}}` is a template and will be replaced with the result after evaluating the statement. Thus, it can not "remove" the `notify` itself, it can only decide what will be notified.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but for omiting params when the Filter returned None, has the param where boolean I couldn't user default(omit, true).

I found the solution [in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters)

```
- name: Execute script
  command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ some_list }}"
  notify: "{{ item | my_filter or omit }}"
```